# Function that adds all nodes at distance "k" from node with element "n" to a list

Tags: python, function, binary-search-tree

Given the class BinarySearchTree, an implementation of the TAD Binary
SearchTree, using only references to the children of each node (_right, _left),
we are asked to implement a subclass of the class BinarySearchTree, which we
will call BST2, and which will include the following methods:

1. find_dist_k(self, n, k). This method receives two parameters n and k which
   are positive integers and will return a Python list containing all nodes that
   are at a distance k from the node whose element is n. The distance between
   two nodes is the number of links that must be traversed to get from one to
   the other. The direction of the links is not taken into account, i.e. the
   distance between node A and node B is the same as between node B and
   node A. If the parameter n is not found in the tree, the method will return an
   empty list. e, it is not allowed to use Python
   structures such as Lists, Queues or Dictionaries, etc.

I can´t do it. It´s forbidden to use "parent"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.